# Ways to split a cube

Tags: geometry

According to someone named [Baumann Eduard](http://www.baumanneduard.ch/Splitting%20a%20cube%20in%20tetrahedras2.htm):

"There exist only 13 manners to split a cube in tetrahedras built exclusively with the 8 corners of the cube without counting simple rotations und (sic) reflections of the splittings."

My question is, how many ways are there in total including rotations?
(for instance, the 13th way has 2 rotations, the 1st way has 4 rotations...)

Also:

How could something like this be determined, except through brute force?

He doesn't cite anything; is there someone who has made a proof or explored the idea fully?

Comment: Note:  the plural of tetrahedron is tetrahedrons or tetrahedra

Comment: Brute force is not so brute in this case; there are very few options to consider at all.